# How to connect to Azure VM by SSH from Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I've created an Azure Virtual Machine and want to use SSH to connect to the VM from Azure Functions. [After reading this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change), I add all outbound IP addresses (Function App -> Networking -> Outbound Trafic -> Outbound Addresses) to the inbound whitelist of VM on 22 port.

It keeps failing to connect to the VM through SSH. Is it able to do it by Azure Functions in the consumption plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MS Doc, `SSH` is only visible/enabled only with the **"Azure Function app premium"** and **"App service hosting plan"** of the azure function app.

***Connecting with SSH is not supported in the consumption plan, and it is also not visible under Development tools.***

1. *I've created a Linux function app which is hosting in an app service plan as shown and was able to connect SSH successfully.*

**Note**: You can also create a function app in a function premium plan to establish the `SSH` connection.

2. Once the function app is created, Goto Development tools and click on SSH as shown in below image.

[image]

**Note:** To open the `SSH port`, Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session) for detailed information.

3. Then it will redirect to the SSH console with the below URL format as given. If it is not redirected, then Goto the browser and place the below URL in the search bar by changing your function app name accordingly.

**URL:** https://newappsss.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host

4. After completing the preceding steps, the following ***Connection was established  successfully***:

[image]

*And also I created and configured the remote connection set up for my function app using **Azure CLI** with the below given commands:*

```bash
az webapp create-remote-connection --subscription <subscriptionID> --resource-group <resourcegroup> -n <functionapp>
```

[image]

```bash
az webapp config set --resource-group <resourcegroup> -n <functionapp> --remote-debugging-enabled=false
```

[image]

Comment: I am still getting the error "The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. Click here for details"

"details": [
    {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"AccountPropertyIsInvalid\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Account property kind is invalid for the request.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
    },